# How to install OpenCV for Python 2 when both Python 2 and Python 3 are Installed on Windows

Tags: python, opencv, command-line

I wanted to install opencv 3 on python 2.7. The problem is that the default config for my system is set for python 3.5 . I know, If I uninstall Python 3, the problem would be solved by pip install and then I can reinstall python 3. But, I can't uninstall python 3. I am using Windows 10 on my PC.

How can I get opencv 3 to install on python 2.7?

Comment: I request not to mark this as repeat, since the other solutions are for Ubuntu or Mac Os, with different set of commands.

Comment: I'm not familiar with opencv, but `pip2` should point to your python2.7 installation

Comment: also something like this works `python2 -m pip install some_module` python2 is your python2 executable path if it is not set in your environment variables.

Comment: Execute the pip module by mentioning the python version: `py -2 -m pip install somemodule`

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it worked fine. Cheers. However, User3080953 , pip 2 wont be recognized by python

Answer (score 0):

```
py -2 -m pip install opencv-python
```

Try this, this worked fine with no need of adding python2 in the system's environment. Then you can just have python3 in the system environment and do a simple pip install for python3.